# Simple nested expression matching with pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I wanted to match an expression which is looking like this:

```
(<some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs> (<more values>) <even more>)
```

I simply want to split those values along the round brackets ().
Currently, I could reduce the pyparsing overhead in the s-expression example[which is far to extensive and not understandable](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/sexpParser.py) (IMHO).

I got as far as to use the `nestedExpr` statement, which reduces it to one line:

```
import pyparsing as pp
parser = pp.nestedExpr(opener='(', closer=')')
print parser.parseString(example, parseAll=True).asList()
```

The result also appears to be split at the white spaces, which I do not want:

```
  skewed_output = [['<some',
  'value',
  'with',
  'spaces',
  'and',
  'm$1124any',
  'crazy',
  'signs>',
  ['<more', 'values>'],
  '<even',
  'more>']]
expected_output = [['<some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs>' 
['<more values>'], '<even more>']]
best_output = [['some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs' 
['more vlaues'], 'even more']]
```

Optionally, I'd gladly take any points to where I can read some *understandable* introduction as how to include a more detailed parser (I'd like to extract the value between the < > brackets and match them (see `best_output`), but I can always `string.strip()` them afterwards.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyparsing's `nestedExpr` accepts `content` and `ignoreExpr` arguments which specify what is a "single item" of an s-expr. You can pass `QuotedString` here. Unfortunately, I did not understand the difference between two parameters from [docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/nestedExpr.html) well enough, but some experiments showed me that the following code should satisfy your requirements:

```
import pyparsing as pp

single_value = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar="<", endQuoteChar=">")
parser = pp.nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")",
                       content=single_value,
                       ignoreExpr=None)

example = "(<some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs> (<more values>) <even more>)"
print(parser.parseString(example, parseAll=True))
```

Output:

```
[['some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs', ['more values'], 'even more']]
```

It expects list to start with `(`, end with `)`, and contain some optionally-whitespace-separated lists or quoted strings, each quoted string should start with `<`, end with `>` and do not contain `<` inside.

You can play around with `content` and `ignoreExpr` parameters more to find out that `content=None, ignoreExpr=single_value` makes the parse accept both quoted and unquoted strings (and separate unquoted strings with spaces):

```
import pyparsing as pp

single_value = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar="<", endQuoteChar=">")
parser = pp.nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")", ignoreExpr=single_value, content=None)

example = "(<some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs> (<more values>) <even m<<ore> foo (foo) <(foo)>)"
print(parser.parseString(example, parseAll=True))
```

Output:

```
[['some value with spaces and m$1124any crazy signs', ['more values'], 'even m<<ore', 'foo', ['foo'], '(foo)']]
```

Some questions left open:

1. Why does `pyparsing` ignore whitespaces between consecutive list items?
2. What is the difference between `content` and `ignoreExpr` and when one should use each of them?

Comment: thanks, that looks like what I had in mind. I'll give it a try later, and accept the answer afterwards, since I can't check it right now.

Comment: In general, pyparsing treats whitespace as ignorable delimiters. Did you find the online help for pyparsing here? https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#nestedExpr . The docs have been greatly enhanced in the past year, about 1000 lines of inline examples added.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I haven't been there. yeputons solution worked for me, though. Thanks a lot!